# Magento - Strange symbol in the invoice's PDF

Tags: php, pdf, encoding, fonts, magento

Hi
I found that there are some strange symbol in the invoice's PDF(Sales > Orders > Action > PrintAll). I am using Chinese language, could this be an encoding problem? How should I fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font used to print PDFs probably doesn't support the characters you want. Take a look in the following two files:

```
Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php
Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Abstract.php
```

Try extending those classes and replacing any references to `/lib/LinLibertineFont/LinLibertineC_Re-2.8.0.ttf` with a font that supports your full character set.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

Or it could be that the font is not being embedded in the PDF.